# NSFontManager setTarget: doesn't work for modal window

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have modal window. In its controller I do this:

```
[[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] orderFrontFontPanel:self];
```

and it works fine. Font manager calls `changeFont:` method in my controller.

But if I write this code instead:

```
[[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] setTarget:self];
[[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] setAction:@selector(qwe:)];
[[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] orderFrontFontPanel:self];
```

it doesn't work. When I select font in font panel it does not invoked qwe: method.

The reason is that window is modal (when I show the window without modal session all works fine). The question is why target-action variant does not work for modal window?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see this, too. Setting the target and the action does not result in the action method being called.

What did work is this: (1) set the delegate, not the target, (2) name the method changeFont, and (3) do not set the action:

```
@property (retain) NSFont *font;

...

- (void)changeFont:(id)sender
{
    self.font = [sender convertFont:self.font];
}

- (IBAction)actionSetFont:(id)sender
{
    NSFontManager *fontManager = [NSFontManager sharedFontManager];
    [fontManager setDelegate:self];
    NSFontPanel *fp = [NSFontPanel sharedFontPanel];
    [fontManager setSelectedFont:self.font isMultiple:NO];
    [fp makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}
```